# MsTeams chatbot, OnTeamsCardActionInvokeAsync method is being hit twice

Tags: c#, async-await, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

Learning about chatbot for MsTeams, I am facing an issue with : WebApp DialogBot.cs class,
method **OnTeamsCardActionInvokeAsync**

It is being called twice sometimes and I can reproduce the behavior when debugging. Not only this method but in general other methods as well are hit twice coming from MsTeams.  These two calls to this method causes my service to respond twice and duplicated messages are displayed in MsTeams chatbot.

Would you know if it is a known issue or if there are some approaches to avoid this behavior?

Comment: When debugging it happens. Because the execution is paused for sometime and MSTeams assumes it's not responding so it sends another request just to make sure it gets the  response. But as it's stopped because of debugging it responds to all request sent.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT thank you for your feedback. You are right , it happens always when debugging. My issue is that it also happens sometimes when executing without debugging, just the chat bot already deployed in Azure. Do you mean Teams sends a second request in case service response is delayed some seconds ? Why it is happening in execution without debugging ? Is there a way to avoid that behavior?

Comment: Yes Alberto, MS Teams sends another request when service response gets delayed. Not able to get proper resolution to avoid this yet.